# The Position of SpriteNode in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am getting start with the SpriteKit, and in my project. I wanna create some grids which falling from the sky and form a grids map as follow:

[image: photo]

I created the physics world with gravity -9.8

and for those Grid, each of them created by the following constructor and add to the scene:

```
class NumberTile:SKSpriteNode{

    convenience init(xPos:CGFloat, yPos:CGFloat){
        var tileColorArray:NSArray = ["#996666","#a65959","#b34d4d","#bf4040","#cc3333","#d92626","#e61919"]

        //get random color from array
        var fillColor:UIColor = UIColor(rgba:  tileColorArray.objectAtIndex(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(tileColorArray.count)))) as! String)

        var size:CGSize = CGSize(width: 38, height: 38);
        self.init(color:fillColor, size:size)

        self.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)
        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0)

        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(
            rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 38,height: 40),
            center: CGPointMake((CGFloat)(38/2),(CGFloat)(40/2)))

        self.physicsBody?.mass = 1000
        self.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false;
    }
}
```

after running a function to drop those grids from the sky. in this case the 6th column's height is different from others. This happens randomly, not a must to happen in the 6th column, any idea?

//Update adding tile creation code

```
func addTileInRow(row: NSInteger){
        var xPos:CGFloat = (CGFloat)(self.counter - 1) * (38 + (2)) + (2)/2;
        var yPos:CGFloat = (self.headerSprite.frame.origin.y - self.headerSprite.frame.size.height)

        var tile:NumberTile = NumberTile(xPos: xPos, yPos: yPos)
        addChild(tile)
    }
```

the counter is start from 1, when counter is larger than 7, it will reset to 1 until 8 rows are created.

Comment: can you post the tiles creation code + actions?

Comment: thanks and updated the question,
but there is no actions in my code, i just set it on the top and let it drop to the ground due to the gravity.

Comment: do the tiles bounce? what makes them stop at the bottom?

Comment: I would advise using actions instead of physics, seeing as physics isn't as controllable. Create an array of positions and move each node to its respective position, or just create them in the desired grid, but offscreen and use a `SKAction.moveBy()` action to move them into view.

Comment: It looks like your are just letting the nodes fall in to place. This is a bad idea.  Position your nodes exactly, then set the physics bodies after they are positioned correctly. Positioning them is simple if you use a nested for loop. You could also try reducing the width of the physics bodies and/or removing friction. It looks to me that the row is being held up, either by a contact force or friction.

Comment: Thanks all, ya, I forgot to mention that I set a ground at the bottom to stop the grid. So, is this a physics engine bug? or it is some common practice?? I still don't get that letting them fall down is a bad idea :(

Comment: You'll get this with most physics simulations, if you want the effect of the physics as well as the exact placement, you can wait until the tiles settle, then move them exactly into place afterwards. If you don't want that slightly random look, then just use an SKAction to place them exactly.